# Routing eigrp between socniwall

Tags: routing, firewall, multicast, sonicwall, eigrp

Hello and good afternoon

well i we have to router sending hello to the multicast 224.0.0.10 
cisco 800 series in both sides, can i form an adjacency between them even if a sonicwall is between the, like sending their hello to the multicast address
i recall in linux you can set the ip forwarding bit in -> /car/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip.forwarding

Maybe with firewall rule?

here is the drawing:

```
-+++++++++-                                              -+++++++++-
 Cisco 800--->Dedicated link<---->Sonicwall <-----> LAN  Cisco 2900
-+++++++++-    X4 no Subinterface    X0 no Subinterface  -+++++++++-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop to think what sort of multicast this is: a local multicast that cannot be sent outside the subnet on which it originates.  You would need to account for that.

You could also use static neighbors in EIGRP to disable using multicast.  You would then need to open the correct port on the firewall.

In any case, you need the interfaces between two EIGRP neighbors on a common subnet.

Answer (score 2):

Sonicwall  won't understand EIGRP cause EIGRP is Cisco proprietary may you try other routing protocol or tunnel the Sonicwall  to forward the traffic without involving in any routing

Comment: So there is no possible because vendor compatibility, but you mean like a gre tunnel?

Comment: yes GRE tunnel would be suitable but don't use IPSEC tunnel cause for more advance IP interconnections needed; such as running  dynamic routing, and load balancing between the sites; then IPSec tunneling itself is unable to support. For such advance IP interconnections, GRE tunneling is the choice. The downside of GRE tunneling is that GRE tunnel is less-secure tunnel compared to IPSec tunnel.